# What is the best way to block spam referrers in an Azure web app?

Tags: azure, spam, azure-web-apps

I have a very low traffic Azure web app written in .net for sharing programming 'books' using a new medium that I created. Currently, I am really the only one creating content on the app.

For the second time in a few weeks I have had a bot (I am assuming) create an account and then use the forms on the app to create thousands of empty books.

After doing a little bit of research it looks like it is a [spam referrer network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spam). I am seeing www.acunetix-referrer.com in my logs coming from Ukraine.

My question is, what is the best way of preventing this on an Azure web app?

Comment: Captchas, email validation for new accounts, and rate limit your "create book" API, especially for new users.

Answer (score 2):

You can block traffic depending on which IP the bot traffic have

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#adding-and-editing-access-restriction-rules-in-the-portal

Comment: The suggestions in the comment by @ceejayoz are excellent too but this was the quick fix I was looking for.